# map(lambda x: int(x, 16) / 256.0, [color[1:3], color[3:5], color[5:7]])

Tags: python, dictionary, colors, lambda, rgb

I am in the process of working my way through a pacman program written in python. One of the modules is handling the graphical representation of the pacman game.This of course some host colours. Here the list:

```
GHOST_COLORS = [] ## establishes a list of ghost colours
GHOST_COLORS.append(formatColor(.9,0,0)) # Red
GHOST_COLORS.append(formatColor(0,.3,.9)) # Blue
GHOST_COLORS.append(formatColor(.98,.41,.07)) # Orange
GHOST_COLORS.append(formatColor(.1,.75,.7)) # Green
GHOST_COLORS.append(formatColor(1.0,0.6,0.0)) # Yellow
GHOST_COLORS.append(formatColor(.4,0.13,0.91)) # Purple
```

These colours are subsequently mapped:

```
GHOST_VEC_COLORS = map(colorToVector, GHOST_COLORS)
```

here the colorToVector:

```
def colorToVector(color): 
  return map(lambda x: int(x, 16) / 256.0, [color[1:3], color[3:5], color[5:7]])
```

I think I understand how lambda works.But I am confused as to how the color slices can be:

1. integrated into the (x,16) tuple,
2. converted into an int --> which shouldn't be possible
3. and subsequently divided by 256.0?

Whenever I attempt to create tuple and convert it into an int in python I seem to get an error.

What am I missing here?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

PS:When I introduce

```
print(color)
```

and

```
print map(lambda x: int(x, 16) / 256.0, [color[1:3], color[3:5], color[5:7]])
```

to the mix I get the following values for the GHOST_COLORS[0] as color:

```
>>#e50000
>>[0.89453125, 0.0, 0.0]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`#e50000` is a string and it has 7 characters. So,

```
color[1:3] == "e5" # Hexadecimal value
color[3:5] == "00" # Hexadecimal value
color[5:7] == "00" # Hexadecimal value
```

Now, one by one, they are passed to the `lambda` function `int(x, 16) / 256.0`. Now, `x` will have `e5`. `int` function's second argument tells that, the first parameter is based on base 16. So, `int` converts `e5` to the equivalent base 10 number and then it is divided by 256.

Comment: Thank you VERY MUCH! This was incredibly helpful, fast and effective. Thank you again.